Can't open a file using WinAPI
I'm trying to use the createFile and it says it can't open it (Could not open file (error 2)). I tried to make the fileName the name of the file and the path to it. The file is just a text file with some words in it. I tried to "Verify File Access", "Testing with a Simplified Path (LPCSTR fileName = "example.txt")", "Check File Path Syntax (LPCSTR fileName = "C:\\Users\\YourUsername\\Desktop\\example.txt")", "Confirm File Location", "Confirm Working Directory".
Original code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Specify the absolute path to the file
    LPCSTR fileName = "C:\\Users\\97250\\OneDrive\\שולחן העבודה\\example.txt";

    // Attempt to open the file
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(
        fileName,                // File name
        GENERIC_READ,            // Desired access
        0,                       // Share mode
        NULL,                    // Security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,           // Creation disposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   // Flags and attributes
        NULL                     // Template file handle
    );

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Could not open file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

Updated code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Specify the relative path to the file
    LPCSTR fileName = "example.txt";

    // Attempt to open the file
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(
        fileName,                // File name
        GENERIC_READ,            // Desired access
        0,                       // Share mode
        NULL,                    // Security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,           // Creation disposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   // Flags and attributes
        NULL                     // Template file handle
    );

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Could not open file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


Trying to open a file with a pathname that includes non-ASCII characters using the ANSI version of the CreateFile API is fraught with peril. Call the Unicode version (CreateFileW) instead, passing in a wide-character string (just prefix your character literal with an L).

@IInspectable applying everything you said. it still gives error 2

If you get error code 2 whether the path is in ASCII or Unicode, it means the path must be incorrect. In the scond case when you just use the file name you must run the program from the same directory as the text file.

If the path contains only ASCII characters, CreateFileA is known to work correctly. So I assume that 1/ the current working directory is not what you expect, causing a relative path to fail or 2/ the full path (containing a user name) contains at least a non ASCII character. I am sorry but the only reliable and reproductible way is to create a top level directory with a ASCII only name (foo...) and then access a file in that folder.

Since I cannot see the changes you applied I cannot comment on why it fails. The updated code is unconditionally wrong, however. The intersection of "using relative paths" and "reliable code" is empty.

@SergeBallesta might be a dumb question, do i call the file "test" or "test.txt"?

@OldBoy How do I run the program from the same directory as the text file?

You need L for unicode string: LPCSTR fileName = L"C:\\...

If your compiler is set to use UTF-8 as the source and execution character sets, you can apply a manifest to the executable to set its active code page to UTF-8. This works since Windows version 1903 (May 2019) update, as mentioned in this answer. Then CreateFileA should interpret your filename correctly.

@i486 The type of a wide-character string literal is LPCWSTR. Using the correct type will immediately resolve two compiler warnings.

Just copy the .exe file from its present location into the same directory as the text file. Alternatively copy the text file into the same directory as the .exe file.

I don't know why, but from the comments I read, the file wasn't in the correct directory(?). I really don't understand any of this, but instead of putting the file in the project's folder "C:\Users\97250\source\repos\learning1\x64\Debug" I created  a top-level directory with a ASCII only name and then accessed the file in that folder "C:\TestFolder" and it worked.
Sorry that it's not specific at all!
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Specify the relative path to the file
    LPCSTR fileName = "C:\\TestFolder\\test.txt";

    // Attempt to open the file
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(
        fileName,                // File name
        GENERIC_READ,            // Desired access
        0,                       // Share mode
        NULL,                    // Security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,           // Creation disposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   // Flags and attributes
        NULL                     // Template file handle
    );

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Could not open file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Buffer to store the data read
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    // Read data from the file
    BOOL readResult = ReadFile(
        fileHandle,              // File handle
        buffer,                  // Buffer to store data
        sizeof(buffer) - 1,      // Number of bytes to read
        &bytesRead,              // Number of bytes read
        NULL                     // Overlapped
    );

    if (!readResult) {
        printf("Could not read from file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return 1;
    }

    // Null-terminate the buffer to make it a valid string
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

    // Print the contents of the buffer
    printf("File contents:\n%s\n", buffer);

    // Close the file handle
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return 0;
}


An answer that doesn't identify the issue is of limited value as it doesn't explain how the proposed solution addresses it.

The current directory not being what is expected is a common beginner's problem with most IDE. You must be aware that is often simpler for management reasons to put the executable file in a different folder that the sources. Then the IDE often choose to launch the executable from its directory, while the programmer has put the data file in the source directory. The rule should be to write the current directory at the beginning of the program (at least at early debugging time) to know where the data files should go.

@SergeBallesta Things are far simpler than you make them appear. The First Rule for Relative Paths is: Do not use. It's still a mystery to me why you wrote your essay about the current directory in response to a piece of code that doesn't rely on the current directory.
